# How to prove generality of a Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f: [a,b] \to X$, is Riemann integrable.

($a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. $X$ is a complete, normed vector space).

Suppose that $(\epsilon_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of strictly positive reals converging to 0. Suppose that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}, (u_n,v_n)$ is an $\epsilon_n$-pair of step functions for $f$.

I'm to show that the limit of $(Iu_n)$ doesn't depend of the choice of sequences $(\epsilon_n), (u_n)$ and $(v_n)$.

The limit of $Iu_n$ is letting $n \to \infty$ and calculating it then, right?

My idea was to show that it doesn't matter how (fast) $(\epsilon_n)$ converges to 0 as long as it converges to 0 (we only to operate with "the last term" in the sequence and the prior ones won't matter after we've made our pick).

And for $(u_n)$ to say that in the intervals where $f(x)$ is constant (ie $f(x) = y$ for $x\in [c,d]$), it doesn't matter how many intervals you partition $[c,d]$ into, you'll still get the same value of $Iu_n$ over the interval $ [c,d]$.

And for $(v_n)$ say that it doesn't matter how you construct it as long
as ($\forall x \in [a,b] ||f(x)-u_n(x)|| \leq v_n(x)$ ) and $Iv_n<\epsilon_n$.

Am I on the right path or have I misunderstood?

Comment: What are $\epsilon_n$-pairs of functions?

Comment: if $(\forall x \in [a,b]: ||f(x)-u_n(x)||\leq v_n(x)) $ and $Iv_n < \epsilon_n$ we call $(u_n,v_n$) an $\epsilon_n$-pair of step-functions for $f$.

Comment: ... and $I\phi=\int_a^b\phi(t)\,\mathrm dt$?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard "$\frac\epsilon3$ proof".

Suppose you have your $(u_n),(v_n),(\epsilon_n)$ and also $(u'_n),(v'_n),(\epsilon'_n)$ with similar properties. Your goal is to show: $\lim Iu_n=\lim Iu'_n$.

So let us assume the first limit exists and let $u:=\lim Iu_n$.
As $\epsilon_n\to 0$ and $\epsilon'_n\to 0$, there exists $N$ such that $\epsilon_n<\frac\epsilon 3$ and $\epsilon'_n<\frac\epsilon 3$ for all $n>N$.
We also have $$ \|u'_n(x)-u_n(x)\|\le \|f(x)-u_n'(x)\|+\|f(x)-u_n(x)\|\le v_n'(x)+v_n(x).$$
For step-functions it is clear (or easily verifyable via a common refinement) that this implies 
$$\|Iu'_n-Iu_n\|=\|I(u'_n-u_n)\|\le I\|u_n'-u_n\|\le I(v'_n+v_n)=Iv_n'+Iv_n<\epsilon'_n+\epsilon_n,$$
and this is  $<\frac23\epsilon$ for $n>N$.
By possibly increasing $N$, we can ensure that also $\|Iu_n-u\|<\frac\epsilon3$ for $n>N$, and thus arrive at $\|Iu'_n-u\|<\epsilon$ for $n>N$, as desired.